# Possible to get an iframe's url cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I get the current url of an iframe on pageload if it is a cross-domain iframe?

Background - I'm trying to enable SSL on my website. However, my users need to be able load any url through an iframe. If they try to load an iframe with http protocol, it will refuse to load because the parent page is https.

I'd like to automatically detect if the iframe is http - and if it is, then redirect the parent page to http. However, with any method I've tried, I get CORS errors when accessing.

Here's my iframe:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src='https://apple.com' onload="this.contentWindow.parent.postMessage(this.contentWindow.document.location.protocol, parent.document.location);" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>
```

And here's my event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) {
  console.log(event.data)
}
```

I am able to receive plain strings as messages, but I'm not able to receive the protocol. My result using window.postMessage() is a CORS error, which I thought was supposed to allow cross-domain communication.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible, for security reasons you can't access other domain/host/port content or src url of an iframe

Comment: Right - but I thought that's what `.postMessage()` was for - to bypass CORS restrictions?

Comment: but you can't send a message from a page you didn't wrote (like apple.com)

Comment: If I replace the first argument in `.postMessage()` with any string, then the page does receive the message from the iframe. So it definitely can send the message.. it just can't apparently read the document object. The iframe is capable of getting an http response from a server, so I would think it should have a way to send a harmless string with the url that it was redirected to? I'm sure you are correct, but I'll still wait a few hours before selecting best answer just in case someone has a clever trick

Comment: To access the location you need to be running inside the iframe script, that means you need apple to send the message for ex.

Comment: The reason you can send the message in the onload is because of the `.parent.`, the message is being sent from window not from the iframe...

Comment: Ah, good call! removing the .parent and trying to run .postMessage() from the iframe gives the following error: `iframe-test-app:23 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3001') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://support.apple.com').` All I need is to access the recipient window's origin.. It get's logged in the console as an error here as I navigate, but is there not a way to retrieve that in JS, even though it's logging it?

Comment: Ah, I see.. maybe it's considered safe to log that url in the console as an error, but unsafe to provide it to the domain?

Comment: you can catch calls to console... but if you can this is terrible! I think the console writing it is the console from the iframe, so you can't