# Show the path of an iFrame element inside of a separate container

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

## The issue

I have the following iframe in my webpage.

```
<iframe id="videobox" width="270" height="410" src="/videochat" marginwidth="0" margin="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

I would like to show the `src` value of this iframe in another HTML element.

```
<div id="iframeurl">iframe url https://abcded.com/videochat/#abcd12345</div>
```

The end of the URL, which is the hash, is dynamically generated when visiting the iframe URL. This means that taking the initial src value will not include the dynamically generated URL.

### Problem

The problem is that taking the `src` value from the iframe only shows `https://abcded.com/videochat/`. I need the URL with the dynamicly generated hash at the end, like `https://abcded.com/videochat/#abcd12345`

## What I need

1. I need the full iframe url inside an `<a>` element like
   `<a href="url-here">Click to open the embed in a new tab.</a>`

**or**

2. I need to show the iframe URL inside of a seperate `<div>` element. For example, `<div id="iframeurl">The URL is: https://abcded.com/videochat/#abcd12345</div>`

Comment: So what is the code that you are using that is not getting the hash?

Comment: Not using any jquery code yet.. But when Inspect source on the iframe it's showing "/videochat" only in src even after hash generated inside videochat/index.html#abcd1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current iframe URL through `.contentWindow.location.href`. Here is an example.

```
document.getElementById("videobox").contentWindow.location.href;
```

To display this in a separate element, set it's `.innerhtml` value to the URL plus any other relevant text.

```
document.getElementById("iframeurl").innerHTML = "The URL is: " + document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href;
```

To make an `<a>` tag with the URL, use this code.

```
document.getElelemtById("iframelink").href = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href;
```

Don't forget to update the JavaScript code once the iframe is loaded after a certain period of time, otherwise it may not pull the correct value and pull the link before it redirects.

Comment: Thank you very much... Can you  give me full example made by jquery  in jsfiddle.net because I will send it to someone have limited knowledge in jquery

Comment: This code does not use jQuery, as it is pure JavaScript. They should be able to understand it if they know JavaScript and the DOM.

Comment: I know.. Its pure Javascript... But they need to see it a. Live.. But thanks anyway

Comment: Ok. I’ll get a live demo up later.

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question. Do you own the webpage that is being displayed in the `<iframe>`? If not, this is impossible due to security restrictions(taking personal info from the URL) See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291523/possible-to-get-an-iframes-url-cross-domain

Comment: thank you for replay.. i made that working now and everything is fine + im learning new things now from you..thank you so much